# Establishing direct connection to ESRI geodatabase on Oracle hangs while not in debug mode

Tags: java, oracle, esri

Recently I have been trying to establish direct connection to oracle geodatabase using Java API.

The problem is, that when I execute the code, the connection works fine only in debug mode when I execute the program step by step. In all other cases the program hangs trying to establish the connection.

Here is a piece of code that I use:

```
public class SdeTest {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SeConnection connection = null;  
        try {  
            System.out.println("Connecting");  
            connection = new SeConnection("none", "sde:oracle11g:geobase_tns", "none", "{my-user}", "{my-password}@geobase_tns");  
            System.out.println("CONNECTION OK");  
        } catch (SeException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } finally {  
            if(connection != null) {  
                try {  
                    connection.freeAllLocks();  
                    connection.close();  
                } catch (SeException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here is my system configuration:

**System:** Windows 7 Professional 64bit

**Java:** 8 update 40 64 bit

**Oracle client:** Oracle 11g 64bit

**ArcSDE SDK:** 10.2.2 64bit

Other settings.

**1.** I have created SDEHOME system variable and its value points to a folder on the disk. Inside the folder I created 'bin' directory and filled it with the following files:

icudt44.dll

icuuc44.dll

pe.dll

sg.dll

xerces-c_3_1.dll

sde.dll

sdejavautil.dll

gsrvrora11g102.dll

sdeora11gsrvr102.dll

**2.** The path to {SDEHOME}/bin is added to the Path of the system.

**3.** The path to {SDEHOME}/bin is added to Java VM: -Djava.library.path={absolute-path-to-bin-folder}

**4.** The oracle databases are fine, I cann see my spatial data with ArcCatalog.

**5.** Here is my TNS definition:

```
geobase_tns =

  (DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS_LIST =

  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = {my-host-ip})(PORT = {my-port-number}))

)

(CONNECT_DATA =

  (SERVICE_NAME = {my-service-name})

)
```

)

**6.** Here is my sqlnet.ora file:

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

What I've already tried.

**1.** I tried to use other java versions

**2.** I tried to add ORACLE_HOME system variable and pointed it to my oracle client installation

**3.** I disabled Windows firewall and my antivirus system.

**4.** I tried connecting to both 9.3.1 oracle geodatabase and 10.3 oracle geodatabase.

In each case I got the same result: stepping in debug mode is fine, running the application freely - hangs.

At this point I am run out of ideas. I can see in my IDE (eclipse - mars) that it holds at SeConnection.createDirectConnection() method.

Can someone give me some suggestions why it behaves like that ? Maybe I missed something while preparing the system for direct connection.

Comment: Can you please paste your `createDirectConnection` method?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because this method is from ESRI jars. And their sources are not available.

Comment: Ok, atleast can you please confirm if that method takes similar arguments as the SEConnection? `new SeConnection("none", "sde:oracle11g:geobase_tns", "none", "{my-user}", "{my-password}@geobase_tns");` Also, did you try using `SEConnection` constructor instead of `createDirectConnetion` method for non-debug mode?

Comment: The method createDirectConnection() is a private method of the SeConnection class. I can only invoke the constructor with the given parameters. So every parameter will have the same value in debug and in normal mode.

Comment: Looks like the parameter order change when in direct mode, also the server name should be replaced by space instead of none. Check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/message/26234777/) link.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I tried several different configurations of the parameters. When they were fine I got the connection while stepping in debug and I got hang - in other cases. The strange thing is that when I put bad params, I got errors while debugging step by step and it still hanged when run freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the 10.2.2 SDE SDK.  [BUG-000087489](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NzQ4OQ==).

Java 1.6 will definitely not have this problem.  That's the workaround I use.  You could also try lower releases of Java 1.7 or 1.8.